# GWT CEll Browser Real Time Update

Tags: gwt, widget

has someone been able to correctly to update a cell browser at runtime, i.e. when u remove a node or add a  node, the change is reflected immediately in the CEll Browser, because I am using a List and when i am making a change it is not being updated on the spot

Answer (score 1):

You can use ListDataProvider setList(...) method for dynamic updates. Here is an example how I update cell browser via RPC:

```
private void loadAllData(final ListDataProvider<Data> dataProvider) {
    dBservice.getAllData(new AsyncCallback<List<Data>>() {
        public void onSuccess(List<Data> result) {
            dataProvider.setList(result);
        }

        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            caught.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to refresh a cellBrowser you have to close all the child on the root node.
anyway something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < cellBrowser.getRootTreeNode().getChildCount(); i++) {
        cellBrowser.getRootTreeNode().setChildOpen(i, false);
    }
```

the AsyncDataProvider calls refreshes data

```
private final class Model implements TreeViewModel{
    private List<ZonaProxy> zonaList = null;
    private List<CategoriaProxy> categoriaList  = null;

    public void setCategoriaList(List<CategoriaProxy> categoriaList) {
        this.categoriaList = categoriaList;
    }

    public void setListZona(List<ZonaProxy> zonaList) {
        this.zonaList = zonaList;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(T value) {
            CategoryDataProvider dataProvider1 = new CategoryDataProvider();
            return new DefaultNodeInfo(dataProvider1, new CategoriaCell());
        }

    /**
     * Check if the specified value represents a leaf node. Leaf nodes cannot be
     * opened.
     */
    public boolean isLeaf(Object value) {
      if (value instanceof CategoriaProxy){
          if (((CategoriaProxy) value).getLivello() == 3) {
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
    }

}

private class CategoryDataProvider extends AsyncDataProvider<CategoriaProxy> 
{
    @Override
    protected void onRangeChanged(HasData<CategoriaProxy> display)
    {
        requests.categoriaRequest().findAllCategorias(0, 8).with().fire(new Receiver<List<CategoriaProxy>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<CategoriaProxy> values) {
                updateRowCount(values.size(), true);
                updateRowData(0, values);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

it Works.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is not enough to change the data provider and refresh it.

You need also to force the affected cell to close and reopen it, as in this example

```
public void updateCellBrowser(String id) {
    TreeNode node = getNode(cellBrowser.getRootTreeNode(),id);

    if(node != null && ! node.isDestroyed()) {
        TreeNode parent = node.getParent();
        int index = node.getIndex();

        parent.setChildOpen(index, false,true);
        parent.setChildOpen(index, true, true);
    }
}
```

In my particular example the cell ids are pathnames hence the following
implementation of getNode().

```
private TreeNode getNode(TreeNode node, String id) {
    for(int i=0; i < node.getChildCount(); i++)
            if(node.isChildOpen(i)) {
                Object value = node.getChildValue(i);

                if(value instanceof String) {
                    String nodeId = ((String) value);

                    if(id.equals(nodeId))
                        return node.setChildOpen(i, true);

                    if(id.startsWith(nodeId))
                        getNode(node.setChildOpen(i, true),id);
                }
            }
    return null;
}
```